# What is the default animation easing function in iOS?

Tags: ios, animation

In iOS animations is the default easing function (`UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut`) a quadratic or a cubic? Or what else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a [cubic bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves). The precise control points aren't documented, so they could change between releases, but you can get them via `CAMediaTimingFunction`:

```
CAMediaTimingFunction *func = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    float *values = malloc(sizeof(float) * 2);
    [func getControlPointAtIndex:i values:values];
    NSLog(@"Control point %i: (%f, %f)", i+1, values[0], values[1]);
    free(values);
}
```

The values I get with this are `(0.0, 0.0)`, `(0.42, 0.0)`, `(0.58, 1.0)`, `(1.0, 1.0)`, which corresponds roughly to this curve:

[image: Curve]

Comment: This is very similar to `3t^2 - 2t^3`, one of the basic [Hermite blending functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline), which you often find implemented in hardware (e.g. `smoothstep()` in GLSL). So you can use that if you want a quick approximation.

Comment: @rickster is correct. You can check this link to compare them.
 https://cubic-bezier.com/#.42,0,.58,1