# How does easing work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, animation, easing

I wanted to perform *Easing* on an iOS application but the closest thing I could find was in `JavaScript`. Here it is

```
const Easing = {

QuadraticInOut: function (k) {
    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
        return 0.5 * k * k;
    }

    return - 0.5 * (--k * (k - 2) - 1);
}, 
 }
```

What does it mean ?

Comment: What's the question? This is a mathematical function that interpolates.

Comment: Are you referring to CSS animations?

Comment: you could have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38497765/1447675

Comment: see the bezier cubic interpolation function. 'Easing' is just a function of time smoothed out. [see this question also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726563/what-is-the-default-animation-easing-function-in-ios)

Comment: [Easing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbetweening#Digital_animation) has nothing to do with javascript in particular. It's the way a property is animated.

Comment: @tadman I don't know what the above data Structure / type is. It  looks like a `function` is being set equal to a `constant` but its confusing. And the last line that returns has  _decrement operator_` `--k` in it.I also don't understand why one would need that.

Comment: @Jack yes I am. It has to do with dragging a curve with control points.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys

Comment: @Tyrone it's hard to tell because it's badly formatted, but it's a property on an object, you can call it just like any other function, e.g. `Easing.QuadraticInOut(3);`. If you want to just use these on CSS animations there's a built in facility for that, without the need for JavaScript, [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)